# Apex Trigger to callout Rest API to external system when the status is updated

Tags: apex, trigger, callout, post

I have a REST API class which will send the response to external system as

```
    {
"AccountId" : "0098",
"email" : "Email-ID",
"status" : "active" 
}
```

Below is the REST API class that will send data to external system from the given endpoint

```
public class AccUpdateController {
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void AccupdateController(Set<Id> accountIdset) {       
        string resultBodyGet = '';

        list<Account> accts = [SELECT Unique_ID__c, Account_Status__c, Email__c from Account where Account_Partner_Status__c = 'ACTIVE' and Id IN:accountIdset];

        system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>' + accts);        
        for(Account c : accts){         

            MAp<String, String> tags = new Map<String, String>();
            tags.put('accId', c.Unique_ID__c);
            tags.put('email', c.Email__c);
            tags.put('status', c.Account_Status__c);            
            system.debug('#### Input JSON: ' + JSON.serialize(tags));            
            try{
                string endpoint = 'https://my-endpoint.com';
                HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
                req.setMethod('POST');
                req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
                req.setbody(JSON.serialize(tags));
                Http http = new Http();
                system.debug('Sending User to update status');
                HTTPResponse response = http.send(req); 
                system.debug('Status updated');
                resultBodyGet = response.getBody();
                system.debug('Output response:' + resultBodyGet);
                accResponse myAccResponse = new accResponse();
                myAccResponse = (accResponse) JSON.deserialize(resultBodyGet, accResponse.class);
                system.debug('#### myAccResponse: ' + myAccResponse);

            }
            catch (exception e) {                              
            }   
        }
    }    
    public class accResponse {
        public string message {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Now, we have a condition that the callout should be done only when the account status is updated. I suppose that can be achieved using trigger. Can anyone help me with the trigger w.r.t the above REST API class so that it fires the records whenever the account record status is updated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please take a few minutes to take the [Tour] and read through [ask]. Please bear in mind that SFSE is not a code-writing service: we expect to see the work you've done so far on this trigger so that the community can assist you with a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can collect the list of accounts whose status changed from the trigger.
In update triggers, we have all old field values in the `old` and `oldmap` trigger context variables.

so you can check for a change in the update trigger, specifically after the update for your scenario. consider your field is `Status__c`.
Below is the code you need to write in a trigger context.

```
Set<Id> accountIdSet = new Set<Id>();
for(Account accObj: trigger.new){
   if(accObj.Status__c != trigger.oldmap.get(accObj.id).Status__c ){
       accountIdSet.add(accObj.id);
   }
}
if(!accountIdSet.isEmpty()){
    AccUpdateController.AccupdateController(accountIdSet);
}
```

You need to make some changes in your future method too.
1. Add parameter to accept `Set<Id> accountIdset`.
2. Query accounts based on `accountIdset`.

```
@future(callout=true)
    public static void AccupdateController(Set<Id> accountIdset) {       
        string resultBodyGet = '';

        list<Account> accts = [SELECT Unique_ID__c, Account_Status__c, Email__c from Account where Account_Partner_Status__c = 'ACTIVE' and Id IN:accountIdset ];
        // other code here
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95806/discussion-on-answer-by-rahul-gawale-apex-trigger-to-callout-rest-api-to-externa).